# How to reference user email from initiator variable?

Tags: workflow, collibra

I'm trying to start one workflow from another. One of the things I would like to pass to the second workflow is the initiator of the first one.

However, when I try to log the value in the console like this:

```
def initiatorVarTest = {{initiator}}
loggerApi.info('Initiator: ' + initiatorVarTest)
```

I see the following in the console: `Initiator: Script31$_run_closure3@6d9d597c`

**How can I extract the user email from the auto-generated initiator variable?**

Originally I had this {{initiator}} line in the builder to start another workflow, but there I got the error that it's expecting a string and that this method cannot handle Script31$_run_closure3@6d9d597c.

Answer (score 0):

I used [How to get all method names of a class without inherited methods with Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065290/how-to-get-all-method-names-of-a-class-without-inherited-methods-with-groovy) to find out what methods this class has.

```
def methods = initiatorVarTest.getClass().declaredMethods.findAll {
    !it.synthetic && !it.getAnnotation(groovy.transform.Internal) 
}.name
loggerApi.info('Methods: ' + methods)
```

Which returned:

```
Methods: [doCall, doCall]
```

I then used:

```
def initiatorVarTest = {{initiator}}
def initiatorEmail = initiatorVarTest.doCall()
```

to get the initator email.